# Lilypond 2.24 on Windows 10 -- can't get log files

Tags: lilypond

### Question (solutions below)

With version 2.24 there seems to be no more `lilypond-windows.exe`, which (without having to know details) did create PDFs, and/or in case of errors log-files.

Now, using v2.24, I have to link `.ly`-files to `lilypond.exe`. which works fine, even by doubleclicking `.ly`-files, but only if these files do not contain fatal errors. Otherwise all error messages disappear together with the command-line that appears for a split second, and no other output is generated. I *would* create a decent command with options for that, but the documentation on command line usage seem to be meant for Liunx users only since several options I tried in command line are answered with error messages.

`lilypond --log-file [...]` -> unrecognized option `--log-file`

`lilypond -log-file [...]` -> unknown log-level `og-file` (which I understand)

`lilypond file.ly &>all.log` -> "syntax error"

I don't use Frescobaldi as in the installation guide, for now I wanted to keep going with Notepad++ and use only the lilypond framework as I did before.

I'm not sure, if this part of Stack Exchange is the appropriate one, but my experience shows, that there are a lot of you knowing much more than just the basic usage of lilypond. I'd appreciate any help.

### Possible solutions

**1.** using the answer from @Lazy
I wrote a batch file `lily.bat` you can drag your .ly-file on, and which does the following:

- change to my Lilypond directory
- execute lilypond with generating a log file in the folder of the .ly-file
- move the generated music-sheet PDF (if it exists) from the lilypond folder to the folder of the .ly-file

```
G:
cd "\Lilypond 2.24.0\bin"
lilypond.exe %1 1>"%~dpn1".log 2>&1
if exist "%~n1".pdf ( move "%~n1".pdf "%~dpn1".pdf )
```

**2.** using the answer from  @ABOU SAMRA Jean I made a shortcut from `lilypond.exe`, you can drag your .ly-file on.

- In the shortcut-properties I specified the *target* as "`G:\Lilypond 2.24.0\bin\lilypond.exe" -dlog-file=out`"
- In the field *Start in* I simply put `%cd%`

This generates the music-sheet PDF and a log file in the folder of the .ly-file.
Unfortunately, for the log-file's name I (due to a pure lack of knowledge) cannot use the name from the .ly-file. If anyone knows how, I gladly edit this section again.

Comment: The expansion flags can be combined, you don't need to write `"%~d1%~p1%~n1"`, only `%~dpn1`.

Comment: @ksnortum Thanks, did not know that. I edited my post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `log-file` option is documented here: https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.24/Documentation/usage/command_002dline-usage.html#advanced-command-line-options-for-lilypond. As explained at the beginning of that section, the correct syntax is

```
lilypond -dlog-file=x file.ly
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a line that can be used in windows shortcuts and is therefore my favourite method. It still isn't perfect, but nevertheless my favourite solution. (Details in my initial questions - I added your answer as a possible solution to my question)

Comment: Just as an explanation: Both answers are equally usable and I had a hard time to decide which answer should be "the one". But since I seem to be using this solution now, I vote for this one. No other reason.

Answer (score 3):

`lilypond.exe file.ly 1>all.log 2>&1` should do it I believe.

Comment: Does Windows recognize that syntax? That's something that would work in bash or other Unix shells, but I wouldn't expect it to work in Windows.

Comment: @Ramillies Yes, it does.

Comment: This works and I used it in a batch file (.ly-file can be drag&dropped). I added this as a possible solution to my initial question. Thank you!